# Function call by value memory leak

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, interpreter

As far as I know, call a function in `C` or `C++` is call by value, meaning while calling functions compiler makes a copy of all parameters and then passes them to the function body.

Hence, is that possible to face with memory leak due to many parameter copying and function calls?

Comment: If the types of your parameters are badly designed, yes. Otherwise, no.

Comment: @juanchopanza badly designed? what does it mean?

Comment: Designed to leak resources when copied.

Comment: @juanchopanza Can I have a examples of this bad approach?

Comment: C++ - can pass by reference. Do you have a example

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani Anything that allocates resources in the copy constructor and does not de-allocate in the destructor.

Comment: Write class which allocates memory in its copy constructor. Pass instance of this class by value. `memory leak due to many parameter copying and function calls`, without any other reason, is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

**Q:** Is that possible to face with memory leak due to many parameter copying and function calls?

**A:** Directly, No. Indirectly, yes.

Say you have two `struct`s.

```
struct A
{
   A(int i) : data(new int(i)) {}
   A(const& copy) : data(new int(*copy.data)) {}

   // Forgot to add a destructor that deallocates
   // memory.

   int* data;
};

struct B
{
   B(int i) : data(i) {}
   int data;
};
```

When you create and delete instances of `A`, you are leaking memory. `B` does not suffer from that problem.

If you pass around instances of `A` to functions, you will create and delete objects, which will lead to memory leaks. That won't be a problem if you pass around instances of `B`.

The point I wanted to make was that passing objects to functions and making copies while doing that does not by itself cause memory leaks. Only when there are memory leaks associated with object construction and deletion will you see the memory leaks while passing them around in functions.

Answer (score 0):

for c, the max stack size is limited,so you can do this make things bad.

```
#define MAX_STACK_SIZE 0x10000000

struct test_s {
    char test[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
}

void func(struct test_s instance){
    //dothings
}
```

but, no one does, instand func as this

```
void func (struct test_s *instance_ref){
    //dothings
}
```